# How can I list all users in AWS Directory Service?

Tags: active-directory, amazon-web-services, aws-directory-service

I'm looking for a way to list all users in an AWS AD (small), preferably with created date (of the user). Is there any way to do this? The AWS console functionality seem somewhat limited. Maybe via the API?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/237548

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks, but this is about amazon. Not MS.